# Logcat : Not granting permission android.permission.BIND_DEVICE_ADMIN to package com.myprojects.myapp (protectionLevel=2 flags=0xbe46)

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-logcat, bootcompleted

I have a boot complete broadcast receiver but it wasnt working as expected. Nor is the Full Screen activity that requires STATUS_BAR permission.

I tried to go through the LogCat logs while the phone was booting up and this is what I found :

**LOG**

```
 04-11 14:23:48.718: W/PackageManager(133): Not granting permission 
    android.permission.BIND_DEVICE_ADMIN to package com.myprojects.myapp (protectionLevel=2 flags=0xbe46)
```

Any clue why would this be happening?

My Manifest file has :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BIND_DEVICE_ADMIN"/>

<receiver android:name="com.myprojects.myapp.DeviceAdministrationReceiver"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_DEVICE_ADMIN">  
       <meta-data android:name="android.app.device_admin" android:resource="@xml/device_admin_policies" />

    <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.app.action.DEVICE_ADMIN_ENABLED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>

<receiver android:name="com.myprojects.myapp.BootCompleteReceiver">  
        <intent-filter>  
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />  
        </intent-filter>  
</receiver>
```

**EDIT**
And other two similar logs :

```
04-11 14:24:17.810: W/PackageManager(133): Not granting permission android.permission.STATUS_BAR to package com.myprojects.myapp (protectionLevel=3 flags=0xbe46)

04-11 14:24:17.810: W/PackageManager(133): Not granting permission android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS to package com.myprojects.myapp (protectionLevel=3 flags=0xbe46)
```

Comment: is that uses-permission is outside the <application> tag?

Comment: Yes, it is. But it works that way, right?

Comment: @sanjana : you are extending DeviceAdminReceiver ?

Comment: Yup that part is working fine. The two things that are not working are : 1) BOOT_COMPLETE OnReceive() not getting triggered and STATUS_BAR that I am trying to make an Activity fullscreen!

Comment: @sanjana : edit post with  fullscreen code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you are extend `DeviceAdminReceiver` then must add *meta-data* and *description* for receiver like:

```
<receiver 
    android:name=".AdminReceiver" 
    android:description="@string/description" 
    android:label="@string/labelValue" 
    android:permission="android.permission.BIND_DEVICE_ADMIN" 
 > 
 <meta-data  
  android:name="android.app.device_admin" 
  android:resource="@xml/lockourscreen"/> 
  <intent-filter> 
   <action android:name="android.app.action.DEVICE_ADMIN_ENABLED" /> 
  </intent-filter> 
</receiver>
```

`BIND_DEVICE_ADMIN` as [doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html) say :
`Must be required by device administration receiver, to ensure that only the system can interact with it.`

so remove `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BIND_DEVICE_ADMIN"/>` line from application level

Comment: it does have the metatags..Have updated the post with the manifest

Comment: remove this line <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BIND_DEVICE_ADMIN"/>

Comment: BIND_DEVICE_ADMIN only for receiver not for Appliction

Comment: yes i have solution but what abut this question solved or not?